# How to set the location of the files referenced by a binary file

Tags: go

When "makensis" binaryfile excutes test.nsi, The "makensis" binary file must refer to  "zlib-x86-ansi" file in Stubs directory. but It searches GOROOT directory. so It cuases error. How can I fix it?

```
GOROOT = /usr/local/go/
/root/go/src/bin/makensis
            /Stubs/zlib-x86-ansi
            /nsis/test.nsi
```

```
        cmd := exec.Command("/root/go/src/bin/makensis","/root/go/src/nsis/test.nsi")
        cmd.Dir = "/root/go/src/bin/"

        var out bytes.Buffer
        var stderr bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &out
        cmd.Stderr = &stderr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
        log.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
        return err
```

```
exit status 1: Error: "/usr/local/go/src/Stubs/zlib-x86-ansi"
```

Comment: Have you tried to change `cmd.Dir` to your path, i.e., `cmd.Dir =/root/go/src/bin/binaryfile/Stubs/"?

Comment: no I didn't. what do you mean your i.e.?  should i change the tree structure. ( ps.   makensis is binary file's name.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try overriding the subprocess's `GOROOT` like this:

```golang
cmd.Env = []string{"GOROOT=/root/go/"}`
```

Comment: It's running. Thank you. What does the source code  mean  that?

Comment: You are welcome! It seems like you have two `GOROOT`s: `/root/go` and `/usr/local/go`. Your system setting points to `/usr/local/go`, but what you really want to use is `/root/go` in this case. Setting `cmd.Env` overrides the system setting.